# Fetch records that took more than two minutes to process?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that has two columns, `processed_at` for when the queue item starts being processed, and `completed_at` for when it finishes.

Here is what I have tried so far, although it gives me a syntax error.

```
SELECT * FROM `queue_items` WHERE SELECT TIMEDIFF(processed_at, completed_at) > 120;
```

**Edit:** I got rid of the syntax error by wrapping the second select in parentheses, although it still doesn't return the desired result.

How can I return all rows in the `queue_items` table, that took longer than two minutes to process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is remove that second `SELECT` keyword (which shouldn't be there*), and switch from an integer to a *time* for the last part.

Then, switch the arguments to `TIMEDIFF`, assuming `processed_at` is expected to come *before* `completed_at` in time. This function does *a − b*, not *b − a*.

```
SELECT *
  FROM `queue_items`
 WHERE TIMEDIFF(`completed_at`, `processed_at`) > TIME('00:02:00');
```

You could also rewrite the condition a little bit to be more expressive:

```
SELECT *
  FROM `queue_items`
 WHERE `completed_at` > TIMESTAMPADD(SECOND, 120, `processed_at`);
```

I haven't gone into any detail about which would be more efficient, as you're going to need a discussion on indexes and whatnot to make any substantial difference there anyway.

* Wrapping it in parentheses turned it into a *sub-query*, which is not desirable or needed here.

Comment: Hi. I have tried your latest answer and I am getting back an empty set?

Comment: Oh, you've got it backwards too. I have updated the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I would simply use a date/time comparison:

```
SELECT qi.*
FROM queue_items qi
WHERE completed_at > processed_at + interval 2 minute;
```

Comment: Yeah or that. Be one with the backticks though!

Comment: As an aside, is `processed_at + INTERVAL 2 MINUTE` exactly equivalent to `TIMESTAMPADD(SECOND, 120, processed_at)`, e.g. as far as the optimiser is concerned? Does it boil down to the same operation? My intuition says "yes" but you never know with SQL... until you do...

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings . . . Functionally, they are the same.  But one looks like 2 minutes are added.  The other looks like 120 seconds are added (when the syntax is fixed, which you have done).

Comment: Gotcha. To be fair, that version can say minutes too ;)